# How to get image height to its parent

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have some code:

```
<section class="header">
    <img src="http://hsto.org/getpro/tmtm-sb/megapost/110/39f/2e2/11039f2e2b5678a644a57a75ec6daa16.jpg" alt=""/>
    <div class="middle-text">
        vertical-align middle text by image height
    </div>
</section>
```

I am trying to make a section which has a responsive image any height. I want it's parent have the same height.

Middle text **may have different height**.
img **may have defferent height**.

Look what I want this image
[image]

Sass like this

```
section.header
 position: relative
 background-size: cover
 overflow: hidden
 z-index: 2
 img
   max-width: 100%
.middle-text
  height: auto
  display: table
  .inside
    display: table-cell
    vertical-align: middle
```

Comment: If your image is width:100%; height:auto and no height is set on your section it will grow with the image. I am also assuming you want the image to be fullscreen

Comment: @Isis you'll have to use absolute positioning something like `.header {position:relative}`  and then `.middle-text{position:absolute; top:50%, left:20%, max-height:20px;margin-top:-10px; }` , also keep the image to `width:100%`; ............ this solution should work if thats all the HTML you have !

Comment: There was a (css3) trick, like this: `top: 50%; transform: translate(0, 50%);` but I don't remember it very well... The idea is to move the element 50% down relative to the parent and then move it 50% up relative to the element itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it something like this with a little more markup:

```
<section class="header">
    <img src="http://hsto.org/getpro/tmtm-sb/megapost/110/39f/2e2/11039f2e2b5678a644a57a75ec6daa16.jpg" alt=""/>
    <div class="middle-text">
        <div class="middle-text__table">
            <div class="middle-text-table__inner">
                vertical-align middle text by image height
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

.header {
    position: relative;
}
.header > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.middle-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
.middle-text__table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.middle-text-table__inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qma9tdkz/2/

Comment: why to make 2 include another 2 divs ? this can be done simply using position : absolute of the child element .

Comment: You don't know the height of the text block, so you can't figure out the negative margin.

Comment: the height can be set of the parent div only, no need for adding another 2 divs

Comment: If you add another line in your example below, the text block will get misaligned: http://jsfiddle.net/0mkqzctm/1/

Answer (score 0):

Make the `position absolute` , and move the text upwards using `margin-top`

> DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/tsx5vbdz/

```
.middle-text{
     height: auto;
     display: table;
     z-index:15;
     margin-top:-20%;
     margin-left:10%;
     color: white;
     vertical-align: middle;
     position:absolute;
}
```